# About the inequality $x^{a^{a^{a^{a^{a}}}}}\geq \left(x+x^{a^{\left(1+a\right)}}\right)0.5$

Tags: derivatives, inequality

It seems we have :

### We have the inequality for $1\geq x\geq a\geq 0.5$:
$$x^{a^{a^{a^{a^{a}}}}}\geq \left(x+x^{a^{\left(1+a\right)}}\right)0.5$$

We introduce the function :

$$q(x)=x^{a^{a^{a^{a^{a}}}}-1}-\left(1+x^{a^{\left(1+a\right)}-1}\right)0.5$$

We have :

$$q''(x)=\frac{({a^{a^{a^{a^{a}}}}} - 2) ({a^{a^{a^{a^{a}}}}} - 1) x^{{a^{a^{a^{a^{a}}}}}} - 0.5 (a^{(a + 1)} - 2) (a^{a + 1} - 1) x^{a^{(a + 1)}}}{x^3}$$

So :

$$q''(x)\leq \frac{({a^{a^{a}}} - 2) ({a^{a^{a}}} - 1) x^{{a^{a^{a^{a^{a}}}}}} - 0.5 (a^{a + 1} - 2) (a^{a + 1} - 1) x^{a^{a + 1})}}{x^3}$$
So it's seems for $a\in(0.52,1)$ :

$$\left(a^{a^{a}}-2\right)\left(a^{a^{a}}-1\right)-0.5\left(a^{\left(a+1\right)}-2\right)\left(a^{\left(a+1\right)}-1\right)\leq 0$$

And for $a\in(0.62,1)$ :

$$\left(a-2\right)\left(a^{a^{a}}-1\right)-0.5\left(a^{\left(a+1\right)}-2\right)\left(a^{\left(a+1\right)}-1\right)\leq 0$$

We can also use with Bernoulli's inequality on $a\in(0,1)$ :

$$a^{\left(1+\left(a-1\right)a\right)}\leq a^{a^{a}}$$

---

We have :

$${a^{a^{a}}}\leq {a^{a^{a^{a^{a}}}}}\quad(1)$$

We have :

$${a^{a^{a}}}\geq a^{(a + 1)}\quad(2)$$

The proof of this is trivial taking logarithm on both side .

We have again combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ :

$$a^{(a + 1)}\leq a^{a^{a^{a^{a}}}}$$

Now it seems that the function is concave so $q'(x)$ is decreasing

Evaluate the derivative in $x\to 0^{+}$ and $x=1$ the function seems to admits a maximum .

Where I'm stuck is to show that the abscissa of the maximum seems to be  greater than $a$

Edit : we have with the constraint above :

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(x^{-1+a^{a^{a^{a^{a}}}}}-0.5\left(1+x^{\left(a^{\left(a+1\right)}-1\right)}\right)\right)\geq \frac{d}{dx}\left(x^{a^{a^{a}}}-0.5\left(x+x^{\left(a^{\left(a+1\right)}\right)}\right)\right)$$

Question :

How to prove the first inequality ?

I'm thanksfull to anyone who have a reference or an argument on the subject .

Comment: Unfortunately I humbly acknowledge that my draft is not sufficient to show the concavity .My bad !

Comment: We can use property wich start from the local to the global since the function is concave .

Comment: We can combine the inequality $a^{\left(1+\left(a-1\right)a\right)}\leq a^{a^{a}}$ with the binomial theorem.

Comment: It is equivalent to $x^{x^{x^{x^{x^{x}}}}}\geq \left(x+x^{x^{\left(1+x\right)}}\right)0.5$ for $0. 5 \le x \le 1$. Is it easier to prove 2-var inequality than 1-var inequality here?